# Understanding the relationship between bar plot, mean average and tscore?

Tags: mean, t-distribution, barplot

I have run three experiments 10 times each, and took the mean for each group. Now I want to plot the results on a bar graph and show the confidence interval for each group. Because I have just performed only 10 tests, I am thinking that I have to use the tscore.

But from this point, I do not how to proceed. Does it make sense to plot the confidence interval using a tscore? I haven't found such examples anywhere on the internet... Or should I just use the mean and not show any confidence intervals at all?

The nature of the experiment is that I have an algorithm which I run 10 times under different parameters. I would eventually like to compare one parameter with another to see if it faster, but just showing the confidence interval is enough.

Comment: What are the groups? What are the variables? What are your research questions? 

(Please edit your question to add this info)

Comment: updated! please let me know if it's ok